# Angular UI-Tree dragged item doen't show floating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I followed the instruction of ui-tree on github. Everything goes fine, except when i drag an item. The dragged item doesn't show in floating style as shown in demo, but the node of dragged item disappear from DOM.

Any idea what could be the possible cause of this case?

Thank you

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?  We are having a similar issue.